# how to improve the speed of drawing a lot of TextItem in pyqtgraph

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

I AM try to mark some location in pyqtgraph,

Here is the code.

```
   def set_history_arrow(self):
        print(f"===> up: {len(self.up)} down: {len(self.down)}")
        for up in self.up:
            print("up", self.up.index(up))
            up_arrow = pg.TextItem('↑', fill=(255, 0, 0))
            self.plot_widget.addItem(up_arrow)
            up_arrow.setPos(up, self.data[up])
        for down in self.down:
            print("down", self.down.index(down))
            down_arrow = pg.TextItem("↓", fill=(0, 238, 118))
            self.plot_widget.addItem(down_arrow)
            down_arrow.setPos(down, self.data[down])
```

the sum of data is:  41363

the count of them,

```
===> up: 4259 down: 2559
```

it is slow to execute it.

How can I improve the speed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use `ScatterPlotItem` will work

Answer (score 0):

If you have a whole lot of text, you may benefit from rendering the text more directly using QPainter.drawText  http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#drawText

There is an example in the PyQtGraph to draw custom graphics here: https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/blob/master/examples/customGraphicsItem.py

That example does not show how to draw text though, and this is not trivial on its own.

This is significantly more complicated, and the suggestion from @somewheve would likely be easier to implement.